# Share dynamic content on facebook using Facebook SDK. How to Include multiple images?

Tags: c#, facebook-sdk-3.0

How do I share multiple images on Facebook? following code snippet shares only one image. How do I modify this code to cater multiple images?

```
            var fb = new FacebookClient();

            fb.AccessToken = strToken
            fb.AppId = strAppID
            fb.AppSecret = strAppSecret


            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.title = strTitle;
            parameters.message = strDescription;

            parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject
            {
                ContentType = "image/jpeg",
                FileName = Path.GetFileName("myimage")
            }.SetValue(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Pictures\image1.jpg"));

            var result = fb.Post("me/photos", parameters);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code for multiple image upload on facebook,

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(token.Trim());
//Perform upload
var imageStream = File.OpenRead(photo.Location);
fb.PostCompleted += (o, e) =>
{
    imageStream.Dispose();
    if (e.Cancelled || e.Error != null)
    {
        error = e.Error == null ? "canceled" : e.Error.Message;
    }
};
dynamic res = fb.PostTaskAsync("/" + fbAlbumID + "/photos", new
{
    message = String.Empty,
    file = new FacebookMediaStream
    {
        ContentType = "image/jpg",
        FileName = Path.GetFileName(photo.Location)
    }.SetValue(imageStream)
});
res.Wait();
var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)res.Result;
```

but each time one popup notification is generated per each uploaded photo.
by  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159260/facebook-upload-multiple-photos-to-album-at-once) question.